# Reading and writing from the BMP180 E2PROM

Tags: stm32, i2c, c, hal

I have been trying to practise writing drivers using the I2C protocol and as a result, I have checked the drivers written for the BMP180 temperature sensor by [Adafruit](https://github.com/sparkfun/BMP180_Breakout/blob/master/Libraries/Arduino/src/SFE_BMP180.h) and written my own some time ago while making some changes and tinkering. The BMP180 is addressed by Adafruit, by using a 7-bit slave address "0x77". I have used this slave address to read and write in the same way i.e. To write to the device:

```
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(i2c, (BMP180_I2C_ADDR << 1), &data, 2, 1000);
```

where "data" will be the data I transmit. I have used  `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive` to read from the device. The above method worked fine, where `Master_Transmit` and `Master_Receive` was used.

However, given the [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BMP180-DS000-09.pdf) of the sensor on page 20, the read-address is "0xEF" and the write address is "0xEE". I had taken the device address as "0x77" for granted. However, now I cannot understand how one derives the "0x77" from "0xEE" or "0xEF". I am trying to replicate the drivers, using `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read` and `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device's I2C slave address is 0x77 - in binary, 0b01110111. In order to write to the device, you must send the slave address bit shifted left by one, with a WRITE bit (0). Therefore 0b01110111 becomes 0b11101110, which is 0xEE. To read from the device, you send the address bit shifted with a READ bit which is 1. 0b01110111 --> 0b11101111, which is 0xEF.

I will also refer you to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662308/what-is-i2c-address-of-ade7878/662310#662310) which is close enough that I thought about voting this question a duplicate.

Comment: @suva23 You already shift the device address one bit left. Did you never contemplate on this expression?

Comment: @thebusybee From knowing the slave address is 0x77, ST specifies that the slave address must be shifted to the left by 1, irrespective, so I took this for granted.

Comment: @Suva23 Right. And what is the result of 0x77 << 1? And what is the reason to shift? See, I like to nudge you to read documentation and to understand what you do. ;-) Did you look into an I²C documentation? It is enlightening!